# Django : Storing important constants in Database and loading onto the project whenever necessary

Tags: django

I am building a django based backend.
There are some very important constants (or you can say data) which defines the functioning of the whole project.

I want to store this information in the database so that anyone with admin permission can update those constants via an api call.

I could store those constants in setting.py file but then I have to edit the python file every time I update it. I want a non technical person be able to update the data via some web form.

One thing I can do is make a database query every time I use those data.

Or is there is some concept of local storage in django like cookies.

so whats the best policy

Comment: Django is optimized to cache the results of querysets in various cases. You should see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) from Django Official Docs that explains caching and querysets.